# Component that returns a JSX element that returns a single function

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I was wondering if it was possible to type a JSX element (or component) that returns a single function as its child?

An example:

```
interface ComponentChildrenProps {
  someProp: string;
}

const Component: React.FC<ComponentProps> = ({ children }): JSX.Element => {
  const propsForChildren: ComponentChildrenProps = { ... }

  const childrenFunction = children as (props: ComponentChildrenProps) => ReactNode;
  
  return <div>{children && childrenFunction(propsForChildren)}</div>
}
```

So in this case, I return only a `JSX.Element`, but I was wondering if it was possible to actually type the `Component` to return a `JSX.Element` that outputs a single function as its child.

Kind of like

```
const Component = (props): JSX.Element<{(props: propsForChildren) => ReactNode}> => 
{ ...component code }
```

In essence, I would like TS to autocomplete the `Component` props when I open the function inside of it, and I was wondering if that was possible

Edit:

This is a kind of generic form component. I'll attach a semi practical use of it below (I stripped it from most of its inner workings not to add too much confusion):

```
const Form: React.FC<FormProps> = (props): JSX.Element | null => {
  const { ... } = props;

  const { handleSubmit, control, watch, formState } = useForm(props)

  const childrenFunction = children as (props: FormChildrenProps) => ReactNode;

  if (!children) return null;

  return (
    <form id={id} onSubmit={handleSubmit(onValidSubmit)}>
      {childrenFunction({ control, formState, watch })}
    </form>
  );
};
```

Usage:

```
<Form>
   {({ control, watch }: FormChildrenProps) => (
     <section>
       <TextField control={control} label="foo" name="foo" />
       <TextField control={control} label="bar" name="bar" />
     </section>
   )}
</Form>
```

Comment: Is that even possible in regular JavaScript React?

Comment: @caTS yup, been using it here and there when needed. Presonally I like the pattern, although I can understand if it's not for everyone :)

Comment: Cool pattern!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alrighty, I have found and answer, and tbh it was just my own lack of intelligence. I guess I just got tunnel vision.

You can simply cast the `children` as a function in the `props`

```
interface FormProps {
  children: (values: FormChildrenProps) => ReactNode;
  ...
}

const Form: React.FC<FormProps> = (props): JSX.Element | null => {
  const { children, ... } = props;

  const { handleSubmit, control, watch, formState } = useForm(props)

  if (!children) return null;

  return (
    <form id={id} onSubmit={handleSubmit(onValidSubmit)}>
      {children({ control, formState, watch })}
    </form>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess it depends on the side effect of your function. You can certainly return multiple items from the component. [JSX](https://reactjs.org/docs/introducing-jsx.html) is merely a template language overlaid on Javascript. If you are wanting to just run the function, it may look like this:

**Running the function**

```
function Component({children}:{children:React.FC<ComponentProps>}): JSX.Element {
...
    return (
        <div>
        {children}
        {childFunction()} // or, to print to div {childFunction().toString()}
        </div>
    );
}
```

I'm not entirely sure what the purpose of the function could be, if using it as a side-effect, you should look at [useEffect()](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useeffect) or [this blog here](https://linguinecode.com/post/react-componentdidupdate-vs-useeffect)

If you just want to pass it along to the child to use, you could set up a state object or just pass it as a prop

```
//Parent
function ParentComponent(...): JSX.Element {
    const funcForChild = () => void; //example function, either received as prop or defined here.
    //using state
    const [funcState, setFuncState] = useState(() => void);
    ...
    return (
        <>
            <ChildComponent function={funcForChild} />
            <ChildComponent function={funcState} />
        </>
    );
}

//Child
function Child({funcToRun}:{funcToRun: (() => void)}) //whatever your type is. Maybe unknown
    useEffect(() => {
        funcToRun() //runs on mount
    },[]);

    return(
        ...
    );
```

**Just returning the elements:**

```
const Component = ({children}) => {
    const jsx = <h1>Hello, World!</h1>
    ...
    return({children, jsx});
}
```

Though, I don't know why you would use the latter.

Could use more clarification. Thanks.

Comment: Hey! Thanks for the fast response.  Sorry if I wasnt clear in my post, I added a "working" example ^^ I hope it helps